# Trying to mutate array within completion block (CLGeocoder reverse geocoding)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I have city names and coordinates stored on my core data database and trying to get the state. 
In order to do this I am reverse geocoding like this

```
code moved below
```

The problem is the `locationStr` object is not getting stored in the `tempCities` array. I have tested inside the block and I know the `locationStr` is getting created and exists.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Can someone clear this up for me?

Tell me if you need any other info.

EDIT:

The array is being used to fill a table view. The code is in a helper method which returns an array (the `tempCities` array). I'm checking the array against nil and 0 right after the for loop.

Heres what the `UISearchControllerDelegate` method looks like in the View controller

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
if ([searchText length] >= 3)
    {
    self.resultsArray = [[[CityHelper sharedInstance]testWithSearch:searchText]mutableCopy];
    [self.resultsTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

And in the `CityHelper` class

```
- (NSArray *) testWithSearch: (NSString *)search
{
NSArray *cities = [self getCitiesStartingWith:search];//stores NSManagedObject subclass instances with cityName, lat, and long.
NSArray *coords = [self coordinatesForCities:cities];

NSMutableArray *tempCities = [NSMutableArray new];

for (MMCoordinate *coordinate in coords) {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[coordinate.latitude floatValue]
                                                     longitude:[coordinate.longitude floatValue]];
    if (![geocoder isGeocoding]) {
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

            NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", placemark.locality, placemark.administrativeArea];
            [tempCities addObject:locationStr];
        }];
    }
}
if (!tempCities) {
    NSLog(@"its nil");
}
if ([tempCities count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"its 0");
}
return tempCities;
}
```

This always returns an empty (0 count) array

Comment: Keep in mind that you are dealing with asynchronous code.

Comment: Actually the reverseGeocodeLocation is called asynchronously, but the completion block is called on the main thread

Comment: The thread is irrelevant to your issue. The values are being added to the array long after the for-loop is done and whatever method this is has long since returned.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize.

Comment: Do you have at least one value added to the `tempCities`?

Comment: Nope. I have 0 values

Comment: @NewEngland Update your question's code with a bit more context. Where is the code you posted so far? Where and when do you check the values in the `tempCities` array?

Comment: Let me know if I should add anything else. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the situation you have can be made clear with a simple code snippet:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // this will be executed in two seconds
        NSLog(@"I'm the last!");
    });

    NSLog(@"I'm first!");
}
```

the block passed to dispatch_after is invoked *after* the method invocation ended, just like the block you passed to `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`. You'll see on the console `I'm first` first, and then `I'm the last!`.

**What should you do?**

You need to solve that problem by introducing a callback to your method, because your method does things in the background and needs to call back when it's done. When you want to know how to declare a block for example in a method, this website explains how to use block syntax: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/

In your case you need also to determine in the `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler` block when to invoke the callback you should add to `testWithSearch` as a parameter. You could for example increase a counter every time you call `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler` and decrease it every time when the completionHandler got invoked. When the counter reaches 0 you invoke the `testWithSearch` callback with the array result.

Example:

```
- (void)doSomething:(dispatch_block_t)callback
{
    // we need __block here because we need to
    // modify that variable inside a block
    // try to remove __block and you'll see a compiler error
    __block int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i ++) {
        counter += 1;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            counter -= 1;
            if (counter <= 0 && callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Who is calling the `doSomething` method? and why 15?

Comment: this is just arbitrary to show you the concept. use the concept and apply it to your problem yourself. I'm not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do the problem for me. I'm trying to understand your example. Thanks anyway tho

Answer (score -3):

Root cause is declaring the `tempCities` as a `__block` variable. Because of `__block`, iOS doesn't retain the `tempCities` on entering to the completion block. Since the completion block is executed later and the `tempCities` is a local variable, it actually gets deallocated at time when the completion block starts execution.

Please declare the `tempCities` as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *tempCities = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: Thanks, but even after doing that tempCities is not nil, but still has no objects.

Comment: I think the answer is closer to what @rmaddy said.

Comment: Actually I'm saying the same. Where do you check count of `tempCities`' items? Within of completion block, i.e. immediately after the `[tempCities addObject:locationStr];` line? Can you please add logging like `NSLog(@"count=%d", tempCities.count);` after this line?

Comment: This answer is misleading. The problem is simply that the completion block is called long after the method returns. Simply removing the `__block` qualifier will have no effect on the result here.

Comment: @rmaddy, the question is when the author of the question checks values in the `tempCities`. If within the completion block then my answer is totally correct. If outside the block then yes, the problem is the code adding objects to this array is executed after checking array's content.

Comment: OK, this answer is for a different question.